# Links don't work with Next.js and Github Pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, next.js, github-pages

I recently followed a tutorial on building a single page portfolio with React and Next.js and it all works fine running locally in development.

However, when I deploy it to Github pages, internal links stop working.

```
    <PrefixedLink href="#about">
      <NavLink>About Me</NavLink>
    </PrefixedLink>
```

I've tried the the following suggestions available online:
Add a next.config.js (this did fix loading images from the public folder) - Mine looks like this:

```
const pathPrefix = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
? '/React-Portfolio'
: '';

module.exports = {
    assetPrefix: pathPrefix,
    basepatch: "/React-Portfolio",
    env: {
        pathPrefix,
    },
};
```

There was also the suggestion to prefix all links as github pages has the project name in the path, so I have this:

```
import Link from 'next/link';

const PrefixedLink = ({ href, as = href, children, ...props }) => (
    <Link
        href={href}
        as={`${process.env.pathPrefix}${as}`}
        {...props}
    >
        {children}
    </Link>
);

export default PrefixedLink;
```

But this also doesn't work.

On the production site the end result looks like:

```
<a class="HeaderStyles__NavLink-sc-9w0vkp-5 jlNUaI">About Me</a>
```

without any href="#about", but if I manually add it via the inspector it works fine.

**EDIT**
Getting rid of the  and adding the href to the NavLink (a customized  tag) fixed the issue.

Comment: `basepatch` should be `basePath` in your `next.config.js`.

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks! Well spotted. Unfortunately, that doesn't fix the problem with links though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting rid of the and adding the href to the NavLink (a customized tag) fixed the issue.